# SWT Section/ExpandableComposite in Eclipse e4 Project

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, e4

**Is is not possible to use Eclipse Forms (org.eclipse.ui.forms) in pure e4 projects?** I want to utilize an ExpandableComposite.

When I start my application using the run/debug configuration everything works find. But as soon as I try to run it from the product configuration or is as a packaged e4 product, I'm getting a **"Missing Constraint: Require Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.forms"** error.

Also, adding org.eclipse.ui.forms to the list of dependencies and starting the product, seems to alter my plugin.xml contents. **After that the CSS style sheet entry is just gone.**

Of course I tried googling, but all I could come up with is this article by Lars Vogel "[Using Eclipse Forms in Eclipse 4 RCP](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/04/02/using-eclipse-forms-in-eclipse-4-rcp/)" where he basically says that CSS styling shall be used over forms, but doesn't say that they don't work together at all.

**If, for some reason this will not work, is there anything comparable to the ExpandableComposite widget?**

Comment: What do you mean by 'CSS style sheet entry is just gone'? Adding a dependency should not do anything like that.

Comment: As soon as I start the software via the link in the product configuration editor, this part of the plugin.xml gets removed: <property name="applicationCSS" value="platform:/plugin/my.software/css/default.css"></property>

Comment: The .product file has a CSS file name on the Customization tab, you probably need to specify the name as well.

Comment: Great! Thanks @greg-449. CSS plugin.xml element is not being removed any longer.
Still the question remains: Have you succesfully managed to use Eclipse Forms with e4? I'm still getting the "Missing Constraint: Require Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.forms; bundle-version='3.6.200'" error. With no hint of how to solve it.

Comment: For a feature based build you will have to add the plugin to a feature. For a plugin based build add it to the list of plugins in the .product file.

Comment: Solved! I had only added it as a dependency of the plug-in which uses it. Now that I also added it to the feature it works. It still feels wrong, though, adding the dependency in two places. Generally, I find dependency resolution in PDE is far from intuitive.