# Is there a collapsible / expandable widget like in eclipse preferences in Eclipse E4 RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp, e4

Is there a widget like `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.ExpandableComposite` in E4? This widget is being used in eclipse preferences page Java->Compiler->Building. I need to use a similar one in E4.

Thanks,
Jehan

Comment: I believe the `org.eclipse.ui.forms` plugin has been fixed so you can use it in e4 in Eclipse 4.5

Comment: Thanks, I found the original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151977/swt-section-expandablecomposite-in-eclipse-e4-project